# Adicionar e Remover campo através do CheckBox

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

Tenho um formulário onde eu seleciono cores para a página, e nele há um checkbox com a opção de `usar padrão do site`, no momento que clico nesse checkbox ele remove o campo, mas quando eu desmarcar o `checkbox` ele deveria criar o campo novamente.

Como faria isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Título', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Digite um Titulo','required' => true]) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Sub-título', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::text('subtitle', null, ['class' => 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Digite um Sub-Titulo']) }}
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="metadata" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cor de fundo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="background" onclick="enableColorsBackground(this.checked)"> Usar Padrão do
        site
        <input type="color" name="background" id="background">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    {{ Form::label('metadata', 'Cor do título:', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="color-title" onclick="enableColorsTitle(this.checked)"> Usar Padrão do
        site
        <input type="color" name="color-title" id="color-title">
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    function enableColorsBackground() {
        document.getElementById('background').remove() ;
    }

    function enableColorsTitle() {
        document.getElementById('color-title').remove();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depois que você remove, não tem como recuperar. O correto seria você ocultar e não remover, de acordo com o argumento passado no `onclick`. Para não enviar o campo, altere para `disabled` quando ocultar (campos desabilitados não são enviados no submit):

```js
function enableColorsBackground(e) {
   var inp = document.getElementById('background');
   inp.style.display = e ? "none" : "inline";
   inp.disabled = e ? true : false;
}

function enableColorsTitle(e) {
   var inp = document.getElementById('color-title');
   inp.style.display = e ? "none" : "inline";
   inp.disabled = e ? true : false;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="metadata" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cor de fundo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="background" onclick="enableColorsBackground(this.checked)"> Usar Padrão do
        site
        <input type="color" name="background" id="background">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="color-title" onclick="enableColorsTitle(this.checked)"> Usar Padrão do
        site
        <input type="color" name="color-title" id="color-title">
    </div>
</div>
```

O argumento `e` da função é o valor enviado em `this.checked`, que pode ser `true` ou `false`. Se for `true`, irá aplicar `display none` (oculta o elemento); ao contrário, `display inline` (mostra o elemento).

Comment: Mas o campo não pode ir para o banco de dados, eu estava usando o hidden, sendo que ele esconde, mas enviar o campo para o banco de dados. Quero realmente remover, mas o que quero era criar novamente, ai não sei como seria para fazer.

Comment: Veja agora.....

Comment: Ele como `disabled` funciona como removee?

Comment: Ele fica desabilitado, não pode ser alterado, mas continua visível. O display "none" oculta. Se vc fizer as duas coisas, como coloquei na resposta, ela fica invisível e não é enviado para o back-end.

Comment: Hum, testar aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Usando Jquery você pode resolver este problema usando a função `toggle()` facilmente, observe que removi o evento `onclick` do `checkbox` e adicionei um `id`:

CheckBox novo

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="metadata" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cor de fundo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="background" id="changeBackground"> Usar Padrão do
        site
        <input type="color" name="background" id="background">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#changeBackground").click(function(){
        if($("#changeBackground").is(":checked")){
            $("#background").attr("disabled","true");
            $("#background").hide();
        }else{
            $("#background").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#background").show();
        }
    });

    function enableColorsBackground() {
        document.getElementById('background').remove() ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: o que esse `toggle()` faz?

Comment: O `toggle()` oculta e exibe o elemento a cada click.

Comment: Hum, mas no caso eu preciso realmente remover ele, porque se ocultar ele vai para o banco de dados.

Comment: Editei a resposta é só trocar os Jquery, o legal do jquery é que diminui consideravelmente a quantidade de linhas, vou apagar o jquery antigo!

Comment: Eu me ligo que o Jquery deixa mais enxuto